# UPSERT with Lead() and Lag() --PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

I'm working with `LEAD()` and `LAG()` for the first time with PostgreSQL, and using case statements. One of my case statements doesn't refer to the lead and lag values at all, and is supposed to do an `UPSERT`.

The `UPSERT` was working perfectly fine before I changed to using the `LEAD()` and `LAG()` in a different case statement. I can't seem to find anything on the PostgreSQL site that would say that these two can't be used together, but it's throwing an error:

```
ERROR:  ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE command cannot affect row a second time
HINT:  Ensure that no rows proposed for insertion within the same command have duplicate constrained values.
```

Is there a reason that when using the WINDOW functions of PostgreSQL that would cause an UPSERT to not work?

This is the code that is throwing the error, I don't reference the LEAD() or LAG() at all in the UPSERT CASE statement, but it seems to be the SELECT statement with the LEAD() and LAG() is what is causing the issue:

```
    FOR rec IN SELECT transactiontime, LEAD(transactiontime) OVER (PARTITION BY identification_number) AS leadtime, LAG(transactiontime) OVER (PARTITION BY identification_number) AS lagtime,
transactiondate, reasoncode, LEAD(reasoncode) OVER (PARTITION BY identification_number) AS leadcode, LAG(reasoncode) OVER (PARTITION BY identification_number) AS lagcode,
identification_number, last_name, first_name, middle_name, suffix
FROM current_working_trans LOOP
    code := rec.reasoncode; 
CASE
    WHEN ((rec.reasoncode = 'TRANSFER IN' AND rec.leadcode = 'TRANSFER OUT' AND (rec.leadtime::time < (rec.transactiontime::time + interval '1 minute'))) 
    OR (rec.reasoncode = 'CHANGE IN' AND rec.leadcode = 'CHANGE OUT' AND (rec.leadtime::time < (rec.transactiontime::time + interval '1 minute')))) THEN 
            UPDATE test_va_new_voter
                SET (sourceid, lastname, firstname, middlename, namesuffix) = 
            (rec.identification_number, rec.last_name, rec.first_name, rec.middle_name, rec.suffix) 
            FROM current_working_trans WHERE rec.identification_number = sourceid;

            DELETE FROM current_working_trans WHERE rec.transactiontime = transactiontime AND nvrareasoncode = rec.reasoncode;
            DELETE FROM current_working_trans WHERE rec.leadtime = transactiontime AND rec.leadcode = reasoncode;  

    WHEN code IN('NEW','REACTIVATE','REINSTATE', 'TRANSFER IN', 'CHANGE IN') THEN
                INSERT INTO test_voter
                (sourceid, lastname, firstname, middlename, namesuffix)
                SELECT rec.identification_number, rec.last_name, rec.first_name, rec.middle_name, rec.suffix    
                FROM current_working_trans
                ON CONFLICT (sourceid) 
                DO UPDATE  
                SET (lastname, firstname, middlename, namesuffix) =
                (SELECT rec.last_name, rec.first_name, rec.middle_name, rec.suffix);
            DELETE FROM current_working_trans WHERE reasoncode = rec.reasoncode AND transactiontime = rec.transactiontime; 
    END CASE;
END LOOP;
```

But when I run this code without SELECT statement with the LEAD() and LAG() and without the first CASE statement, it works:

```
FOR rec IN SELECT *
FROM current_working_trans LOOP
    code := rec.reasoncode; 
CASE
    WHEN code IN('NEW','REACTIVATE','REINSTATE', 'TRANSFER IN', 'CHANGE IN') THEN
                INSERT INTO test_voter
                (sourceid, lastname, firstname, middlename, namesuffix)
                SELECT rec.identification_number, rec.last_name, rec.first_name, rec.middle_name, rec.suffix    
                FROM current_working_trans
                ON CONFLICT (sourceid) 
                DO UPDATE  
                SET (lastname, firstname, middlename, namesuffix) =
                (SELECT rec.last_name, rec.first_name, rec.middle_name, rec.suffix);
            DELETE FROM current_working_trans WHERE reasoncode = rec.reasoncode AND transactiontime = rec.transactiontime; 
    END CASE;
END LOOP;
```

I've tested the first case statement that uses the LEAD() and LAG() separately and that works when it's by itself as well.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the query? Sometimes errors are not enough to get whats wrong. Also, you can check this article on "[how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)".

Comment: @Dan I've updated the question with a short example of the code that is throwing the error. Thank you